# Understanding Eloquent Javascript partial function

Tags: javascript, dictionary, higher-order-functions

Eloquent Javascript contains the following code examples:

```
function map(func, array) {
  var result = [];
  forEach(array, function (element) {
    result.push(func(element));
  });
  return result;
}

function asArray(quasiArray, start) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = (start || 0); i < quasiArray.length; i++)
    result.push(quasiArray[i]);
  return result;
}

function partial(func) {
  var fixedArgs = asArray(arguments, 1);
  return function(){
    return func.apply(null, fixedArgs.concat(asArray(arguments)));
  };
}

function square(x) {return x * x;}

console.log(map(partial(map, square), [[10, 100], [12, 16], [0, 1]]));
```

I understand `map` and `asArray`, but `partial` is confusing to me.  The above call returns

```
[[100, 10000], [144, 256], [0, 1]]
```

but I don't understand how.  Here are my questions:

1) In the `partial` definition, is the `arguments` variable in the first line the same as the `arguments` variable in the last line?  If not, what are the sources for each of those arguments objects?

2) When the function call occurs on the final code line above, my understanding is that `fixedArgs` is bound to `[square]` (that is, an array containing the square function).  Then `concat` is called on it with the 2-dimensional array.  Many problems, and not the correct answer, arise from these bindings, so they can't be the correct ones.  How are the variables in partial bound when it's called?

Comment: For others who might also be confused by this code, I want to add that `apply` (used in the fourth line of the `partial` function) is a built-in function method that takes two parameters: 1) what `this` will be set to (a topic all by itself; for this code, it's ok for this example to think of `null` as an inert placeholder), and 2) an array that contains all of the arguments that will be supplied to the function that `apply` is being called on.  In this case, that array is [square, [[10, 100], [12, 16], [0, 1]]].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) No, they're different. `arguments` in the first line contains the arguments to `partial`. `arguments` in the last line contains the arguments to the anonymous function that `partial` returned.

2) `fixedArgs` contains the array `[square]`. Since it was created from `asArray(arguments, 1)`, it skips argument 0, which is `map`, and contains all the remaining arguments.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) In the partial definition, is the arguments variable in the first line the same as the arguments variable in the last line? If not, what are the sources for each of those arguments objects?

**No it's not**. `arguments` is based on the [*current* function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6). In the first line it's the arguments supplied to `partial` itself, in the third one it's the arguments applied to the function.

To quote the specification:

> When control enters an execution context for function code, an arguments object is created

What we're doing here is applying the arguments supplied initially *in addition* to the ones supplied later on. We're concating the arguments given initially with the ones given during invocation to create a partial.

> 2) When the function call occurs on the final code line above, my understanding is that fixedArgs bound to [map] (that is, an array containing the map function). Then concat is called on it with the 2-dimensional array. Many problems, and not the correct answer, arise from these bindings, so they can't be the correct ones. How are the variables in partial bound when it's called?

What the code in the last line is doing is:

- `partial(map, square)` - creates a function out of `map` that uses `square` as the first argument, this basically creates a function that gets an array and squares it.
- `map(result, [[10, 100], [12, 16], [0, 1]])` - this performs a mapping again. This time we map every element in the array to the function declared above. The elements in the array are arrays themselves and the function we defined above takes an array and squares all its elements so what it does is square all the elements of the internal arrays.

So we get expect to get `[100,1000],...`

Answer (score 2):

1) `arguments` is a special JavaScript variable. It is an array of all arguments passed to that function. So those `arguments` are two different variables: The first one refers to the arguments passed to `partial`, the second one to those passed to the returned function.

2) The `partial` function returns a new function that, when invoked, calls `map` with `square` as the only argument. The outer `map` call processes all arrays in the given (two-dimensional) array: `map` processes each part, `partial(map, square)` prepares a function that squares all values in the passed array.

Edit: I am definitely typing too slowly.

Comment: Where are arguments passed to `partial`'s returned function?  (And, FYI, `arguments` isn't an array, technically: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/javascripts-arguments-object-and-beyond/)

Comment: @rainbowsorbet `map` calls the returned function passing every single item in the array `[[10, 100], [12, 16], [0, 1]]` as an argument. So it calls the returned function three times, which then calls `map` with `square` and its own argument (e.g. `[10, 100]`).